# Set cookie using ngx-cookie for apollo calls

Tags: angular, cookies, graphql

I am working on an Angular4 app, using Apollo to call a GraphQL server. I need to provide a cookie value on the calls to GraphQL.

I have tried the library angular2-cookie, and am now trying ngx-cookie, to try to set a cookie value like this:

```
this.cookieService.put('mycookie', 'mycookievalue');
```

I then expect that when I run something like this:

```
return this.queryService.query(`
     mutation DoThing($inputz: ThingInput!) {
         ThingDoer(input: $inputz) { outputThing }
     }
    `, {
(...)
```

I should see a header on that call when I look at it in Chrome:

```
Cookie: ...;mycookie=mycookievalue;...
```

But no such cookie value gets passed.

I have tried specifying domain and path as options to the put call:

```
this.cookieService.put('mycookie', 'mycookievalue', {
  path: 'http://example.com',
  domain: 'http://example.com',
  secure: false
});
```

including path, domain or both. No result.

What am I not getting right?

Answer (score 1):

I found it - it's me who don't understand properly how cookies work.

I had another app running that had set mycookie=mycookievalue on a different subdomain (e.g. my app is running on a.example.com and the other app is running on b.example.com). Apparently that meant I couldn't use mycookie on my subdomain. When I removed the other cookie with the same name, my cookie suddenly started working.